# AWS Lambda has "Failed to PutOrAdd in database because not enough space for domain" problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I'm writing lambda functions on AWS, it worked fine before. But today, when I was editing my code, the error came up. I'm not able to edit my functions and save them now. I have tried to delete the lambda functions and add a new one, but it has the same error.

[image]

I guess there's might have a temporary directory and I can remove the temp files to clean up the space, but I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems like the issue is with AWS and with the temp directory we manage. Every lambda execution creates a docker container hosted by aws on amazon linux. Seems like storage or some issue from AWS!

Comment: You should probably contact AWS support.

Comment: I did try to find how to contact AWS support, but it seems very difficult to get support if you are a individual user  instead of a company user :(

Comment: Have you hit the 75gb storage limit for Lambdas?

Comment: @hephalump No, I only use 1.2 kB storage :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a problem from AWS. It back to normal the day after I posted the question, I didn't do anything. So I think it wasn't my problem, it was an issue from AWS.